# Xcode12 doesn't offer struct when editing

Tags: xcode

Xcode doesn't offer the struct org_bluetooth_characteristic_date_time in *measurement.swift despite the *date_time.swift was imported previously.

[image]

The *date_time.swift is just also a struct like this:

[image]

I've tried to import, but with no luck. Is this normal xcode behavior, that xcode cannot find definitions in another file?

Comment: Code completion is wonky sometimes, unfortunately. Actually compiling your project and/or restarting Xcode sometimes helps.

Comment: Yes, restarting xcode helps.